# Jquery Hide with two drop down selects

Tags: jquery, hide

I have two drop down selects. One is called 
Disciplines, the other is called MensLevels
They both share the same ID
based on the value of the first select, how do I hide the second select?
here is my code:

```
    $("select[name=Disciplines]").change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'Acro') {
                var PID = $(this).attr('id');
                $('td:nth-child(6).attr("id") == "' + PID + '"').hide(); 
            }
    });
```

Comment: I don't see a question.

Comment: Can you add your HTML?

Comment: I think we'll need a little more code than this, where's your html and what do you mean by "I want to hide the second select"?

Comment: you say you're trying to hide a select, are those select elements child elements of these 'td' elements you're selecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("select[name=Disciplines]").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Acro') {
        $('select[name=MensLevels][id="' + this.id + '"]').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: this answer should be flagged for making me look like a fool

Answer (score 1):

first of all the value "Disciplines" in the selector for the `.change` event has to have quotes around it like so: "select[name='Disciplines']" and not the way you have it without the quotes: "select[name=Disciplines]"

could this be what you're looking for?:

```
$("select[name='Disciplines']").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Acro') {
            var PID = $(this).attr('id');


            $('#' + PID).each(function(index){
                if(index > 0 && $(this).attr("name") != "Disciplines"){
                   $(this).hide();
                   return true;
                }
            });
        }
});
```